# Set instance variables using hash

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I'm trying to set instance variables without perforating my object with single setters. I'd like to do it using a method that I call a *group setter*.

I want to iterate through an object's `instance_variables`, and for those that match a key in a hash provided in advance, set them individually using `instance_variable_set`. I do not want to iterate through the hash pairs to qualify the setting of the instance variables because that is a security issue.

This is my code:

```
class Pickle
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :colour, :status

  def initialize()
    @id = nil
    @name = nil
    @colour = 'green'
    @status = 'new'
  end

  def into_me(incoming)
    instance_variables.each do |i|
      puts i
      puts incoming[i]
      instance_variable_set(i, incoming[i])
    end
  end
end

a = Pickle.new
# >> @id
# => #<Pickle:0x00007fef6782c978 @colour="green", @id=nil, @name=nil, @status="new">

newstuff = {:name => 'Peter', :colour => 'red'}
a.into_me(newstuff)
# >> @name
# >> @colour
# >> @status
# => #<Pickle:0x00007fef6782c978 @colour=nil, @id=nil, @name=nil, @status=nil>
```

It's close, but it can't seem to find the provided key/value pair in the hash. I don't see why it can't use the provided hash to look up symbols as keys.

What am I doing wrong?

It is NOT a duplicate and answered before, because of the mismatch on `instance_variable` variable types.  If you read the post it says `It's close, but it can't seem to find the provided key/value pair in the hash. I don't see why it can't use the provided hash to look up symbols as keys.`.

Comment: because `:name` is not the same as `@name`

Comment: @Joe `:id = nil` in `initialize()` throws an error.  It's not clear to which you are referring.

Comment: `puts incoming[i]` is never going to match, because `i` from `instance_variables.each` is returning items like `@name` but your incoming hash has symbolic keys like `:name`

Comment: Can that not be parsed out into proper form?

Comment: Can you explain why iterating over the properties vs. the hash is a better solution?  You could mess with strings here, stripping off the `@` and then calling `.to_sym` to match them up, but that seems pretty messy for an unclear benefit.

Comment: I did below.  There's a valid reason for restricting the scope of the assignments from the object out, instead of traversing a hash and blindly assigning or creating instance vars based on a provided hash.

Comment: There really isn't, if your goal is to call any setters on the object for any values in the hash that might exist.  You're blindly assigning in either case.

Comment: As you have actually answered below, and as I have said in the OP, there is a missing qualifier on testing for actually instance variables in the object.  The less reliability on the size and integrity of the hash, the better.  So I chose to call from the object instead.  I never want an `instance_variable` simply because some garbage was in the hash, for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

One way I've done this is to flip the assignment around e.g.

```
def initialize(**h)
    h.each do |k, v|
        setter = "#{k}="
        next unless respond_to? setter # skip if we don't have a setter for this key
        public_send setter, v
    end
end
```

This processes the incoming hash and calls the assignment op for each one that is found in the hash.  It will skip any values that don't have explicit setters.

Comment: Ya that's what I meant about reversing the focus.  I don't like that because of the loose incoming hash.  I want to filter the new instance var assignments by implementing this as a method, not a push using the iteration of the hash.

Comment: Why is that a "security issue"?

Comment: The provided hash is coming from the outside.  It might be form parameters, or from somewhere else.  To avoid having to qualify the hash as being safe, it's easier to just use a method that traverses the `instance_variables`.  That's why I put this in the OP.  I don't want to start writing validations for incoming hashes.  That defeats the point of all this.

Comment: Is "safe" mean that the hash doesn't contain values outside of your declared setters?  That's easily handled without having to manually verify the hash.  See edit.

Comment: Well that's just it.  You don't know that, nor do you want to find out, because someone's injecting somehow.  The `setter` is the method I'm trying to accomplish, from the method outwards, by asking the hash instead of shoving the hash into the object.  Ah I see your internal qualifier.  I'll review.  Thanks.